# Notch for Docked FloatingActionButton Missing in BottomAppBar

Tags: dart, flutter

### Once

You can **dock** a *`FloatingActionButton`* by specifying `floatingActionButtonLocation` in a `Scaffold` and using `BottomAppBar`.

The [documentation](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/floating_action_button_location.dart#L64) talks about a:

> "notch"

[image: docked fab]

### Now

[image: screen capture]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
      child: Container(
        height: 300.0,
        color: Colors.pinkAccent,
      ),
    ),
    floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {}),
  ),
));
```

With ***Flutter** version* `0.5.6`, I am unable to recreate the notch. The second image and the code below it belong together.

Is this *an issue/bug* or is there anything I can, now, do about it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `BottomAppBar` now needs its `shape` specified as [`CircularNotchedRectangle`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/notched_shapes.dart#L28), which is not set as a default like the former `hasNotch` was:

```
Scaffold(
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(...),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
    ...
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to specify **shape: CircularNotchedRectangle()** and **clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias**(or Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer)

full code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        child: Container(
          height: 60.0,
          color: Colors.pinkAccent,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {}),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Notches are optional/configurable. In the [beta](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/beta/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_app_bar.dart) branch, you get them by setting the `hasNotch` property in the constructor.

However, it's looked like this has changed in the [dev](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/dev/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_app_bar.dart) branch (and in the 0.5.6 version you specified). Here, you specify a `shape` for the notch instead. The [Flutter Gallery](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/v0.5.6/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/bottom_app_bar_demo.dart)
has a nice demo of how to make one of these. They also offer what looks like a [default implementation for circles](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/472bbccf756e7954af2a81d2c8abc46d65a570af/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/notched_shapes.dart#L28).

You could probably just do:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
      shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
      child: Container(
        height: 300.0,
        color: Colors.pinkAccent,
      ),
    ),
    floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {}),
  ),
));
```

Comment: The branches are probably not helpful for the future. Anyways, you got something a little bit wrong in your code. I figured it out with the help of [Raouf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51253188/6509751).

Comment: Good feedback! Code is updated. Leaving the branches in for now, since your answer is basically equivalent if I take them out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,
there is a pull request for that:

[Move the notch computation from the FAB to the BAB. #18372](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/18372)

Answer (score 1):

Haha, I just tried making it too, and was confused why this is so difficult.

Solution: It does need the shape, but ALSO move the color out of the Container, and into the BottomAppBar.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
      child: Container(
        height: 300.0,
      ),
      color: Colors.pinkAccent,
    ),
    shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
    floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {}),
  ),
));
```

That colors the BottomAppBar correctly, with notch and everything. If the container is colored it is colered OVER the BottomAppBar, and will cover the noth.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
      clipBehaviour: Clip.antiAlias,
      shape: new CircularNotchedRectangle(),
      notchMargin: 5.0,
      child: Container(
        height: 300.0,
        color: Colors.pinkAccent,
      ),
    ),
    floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {}),
  ),
));
```