# [Flutter]: FAB for only one bottom tab

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-bottomnavigation

I have a `BottomAppBar` that has a `FloatingActionButton`. However, I only want this button to be seen in one particular screen. In the best case, I'd like to add this button only when the user clicks on that particular screen.

I've found that you can add a `FAB` like this:

```
return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      extendBody: true,
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          ...
        },
        child:  const Icon(
          Icons.add_sharp,
          color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: buildBottomNavigationBar(),
    );
```

However, as you can see this `Scaffold` is shared by all the screens that can be selected in the `bottomNavigationBar`. How do I add a `FAB` only for a particular screen?

I'd like the `FAB` to be embedded into the `bottomNavigationBar` so I do not want to add a plain button to that particular screen. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution was actually quite simple and I was overthinking stuff. I have a variable that keeps track of the currently open screen. So I simply added this little logic to the mother screen that hosts the `bottomNavigationBar`:

```
if (_selectedIndex==1){
  // Other screen that needs the FAB
  return Scaffold(
    ...,
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        ....
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: buildBottomNavigationBar(),
  );
}

return Scaffold(
  ...,
  bottomNavigationBar: buildBottomNavigationBar(),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Josip Domazet is absolutely right, but it can be achieved with shorter workaround instead of creating different Scaffold, using conditional operator as

```
floatingActionButton: _selectedIndex==1
      ? FloatingActionButton(....) : const SizedBox.shrink(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Stack In your Specific Tab and Add FAB at the bottom :

Example :

```
    Stack(
children[
    
    Container(height: double.infinity,
    width: double.infinity) // for full screen 
    
    Position(
    bottom : 10,
    left: 150,
    right : 150,
    child: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              ...
            },
            child:  const Icon(
              Icons.add_sharp,
              color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
            ),
          )
    )
    
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap that specific screen with scaffold again and use fab on that screen only.

Comment: Wrapping that screen does indeed display a new fab. However, the fab is underneath the existing `bottomNavigationBar` of the previous scaffold. I need the fab to be part of that  `bottomNavigationBar`. This is because I need to achieve a notch effect like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51251722/notch-for-docked-floatingactionbutton-missing-in-bottomappbar